# Multiplicity and signals of cis−[(Ph3P)2PtF2] in two NMR spectra

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I am interested in the number of the signals and their multiplicities in the  $\ce{^{31}P\{^1H\}}$ and $\ce{^{19}F\{^1H}\}$ NMR spectra of $\ce{[\textit{cis-}(Ph3P)2PtF2]}$. It is given that $\ce{Pt}$ has $I=1/2$.

I believe that in both spectra we have a triplet signal. Furthermore, I wonder if in the $\ce{^{31}P\{^1H\}}$ spectrum the signal can be split by $\ce{F}$ and, similarly, if in the $\ce{^{19}F\{^1H}\}$ $\ce{NMR}$ spectrum the signal can be split by $\ce{P}$.